# How to exclude objects connected via ForeignKey Django?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class AnimalX(models.Model):
    my_animal = models.ForeignKey('animals.MyAnimal', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='animals')

class MyAnimal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I'd like to get all the MyAnimal instances that do not have AnimalX instance.

Do you have any idea how can i achieve this?
I thought about doing MyAnimal.objects.all().exclude(AnimalX.objects.all())
but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
MyAnimal.objects.filter(animals=None)
```